# creating rows update event handler for a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, event-handling

I am writing a web application using VB and ASP.Net with a SQL server database. i am trying to create a gridview_RowUpdated and gridview_RowsDeleted event handler to display an error message if there are any exceptions. When i double click on the grid view to create a new event handler the one that is automatically created is GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged. Is there a proper way to have these event handlers created for me automatically or do need write out the code by hand for these event handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top left of the code window, select your datagridview object in the drop down (right underneath the tab that shows the filename).  Then in the dropdown to the right, you'll be able to select from all of the events that it supports and it will automatically create the event's subroutine when you select it.

Comment: thank you! i didn't even know that was a drop down menu. i'd up vote you but i don't have the required reputation as i am new here and to programming.